# How to efficiently diversify Dijkstra's algorithm (while preserving shortest path(s))?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dijkstra, path-finding

### Please look at the images and their descriptions below.

P.S. ignore the gray circular boundary (that's just max radius for debug testing).

---

[image: Figure 1]

**Figure 1:** No shuffling of branches. Branches are in order: `Top, Left, Down, Right`

[image: Figure 2]

**Figure 2:** Has branch shuffling: every time a node branches to its 4 potential children, the order is randomized.

---

So, as you can see the four images have the same path length. The lower 3 are more diverse, and are preferred. Shuffling the order of the array at every branch seems a bit inefficient. Any ways to improve it?

My idea is that I could create a list of all the possible shuffles (since there are 4 elements, that should be 24* permutations, right?), and generate a random number which will be used as an index to the list.

Are there any alternatives? Or perhaps I should look into a different algorithm altogether?

P.S. this is for game development purposes, so the diversity for paths is highly preferred.

Comment: You don't want the same order every time, and you don't want a shuffled order. That doesn't exactly leave much...

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm just asking if there are any efficient alternatives. I'm a student so there are lots of stuff I don't know. Just hoping someone more knowledgeable can come and shed light.

Comment: What you _mean_ is "I definitely want to at least pseudo-shuffle the order, what's the most efficient way to do that?"

Answer (score 2):

Every time you calculate the path length to a node, before comparing against its previous best length, add a small random number so that the calculated length is between real_length and real_length+0.5.  This will randomize the choices between paths of equal length.